# Finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

On page 68 of the book p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Functions by Koblitz, the following corollary is stated:

If $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of degree $n$, index of ramification $e$, and residue field degree $f$, and if $\pi$ chosen so that $\text{ord}_p \pi = \frac{1}{e}$, then every $\alpha\in K$ can be written in one and only one way as $$\sum_{i=m}^\infty a_i\pi^i$$where $m=e\cdot \text{ord}_p\alpha$ and each $a_i$ satisfies $a_i^{p^f}=a_i$

The proof of this corollary has been left as an exercise to the reader (me), with the remark that it is easy. However, I have no idea where to start. The proposition before this corollary is

There is exactly one unramified extension $K^{\text{unram}}_f$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of degree $f$, and it can be obtained by adjoining a primitive $(p^f - 1 )$th root of $1$. If $K$ is an extension $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of degree $n$, index of ramification $e$, and residue field degree $f$ (so that $n = ef$), then $K = K^{\text{unram}}_f(\pi)$, where $\pi$ satisfies an Eisenstein polynomial with coefficients in $K^{\text{unram}}_f$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $x^{p^f}-x$ splits completely in $K$. Any element of $K$ can be approximated (in a unique way) by finite sums $\sum_{i=m}^M a_i\pi^i$

Comment: I don't completely follow. I assume that you know the first line of your comment from the fact that $K^\text{unram}_f$ is obtained by adjoining a primitive $(p^f-1)th$ root of $1$. But doesn't this mean that $K$ contains a root of the polynomial $x^{p^f-1}-1$? If so, I don't see how to derive from there that your polynomial splits completely in $K$.

Comment: That's what your book is saying, that $x^{p^f}-x$ splits completely in $O_K/(\pi)$ implies that it splits completely in $K$. The proof is easy: if $b\bmod (\pi)$ is a primitive $p^f-1$-th root of unity in the residue field then $\lim_{m\to \infty} b^{p^m}$ is a primitive $p^f-1$-th root of unity in $K$.

Comment: What is $O_K$? Did you mean something else?

Comment: $O_K$ is the subring of elements of non-negative valuation, those that are integral over $\Bbb{Z}_p$, it is a DVR with maximal ideal $(\pi)$ and its residue field is $\Bbb{F}_{p^f}$ (that's the definition of $\pi$ and $f$)

Comment: I see. Another way of describing this ring is would be $O_K=\{x\in K:|x|_p\leq 1\}$, am I correct? How do I know that your polynomial splits completely in $O_K/(\pi)$?

Comment: $O_K/(\pi) $ is a finite field with $p^f$-elements, all the non-zero elements are roots of $x^{p^f-1}-1$, so $x^{p^f}-x$ has $p^f$ distinct roots, it splits completely (this is how we prove that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic)